# Create a loop switcher between different operations in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have three looped operations `O1 O2 O3` each with an **IF** statement and the operation with the largest `flag=[F1 F2 F3]` value has a higher priority to run.

How can I switch between operations depending on the value of that `flag` ? The flag value for each operation varies with time.

For simplicity, operation 1 is going to run first, and by the end of it's loop the flag value will be the lowest, hence operation 2 or 3 should run next. So for this example, at `t=0 : F1=5 F2=3 and F3=1.`

The over-simplified pseudo code for what im trying to achieve :

```
while 1
  find largest flag value using [v index]=max(flag)
  Run operation with highest flag value
   ..loop back..
end
```

I am not sure how the value of flag will be compared in between operations, and hence why I hope for someone to shed some light on the issue here.

**EDIT**

Currently, all operations are written in one matlab file, and each is triggered with an IF statement. The operations run systematically one after the other (depending on which one is written first in matlab). I want to avoid that and trigger them depending on the `flag` value instead.

Comment: There is no 'answer' because this isn't a standard technique with something built in... so it will be handled however *you* handle it.  Clarify your goals, either you'll figure out a solution or at the least it will help those trying to help you.

Comment: I guess @learnvst is pretty much spot on with his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your operations are functions (a little hard to tell from the question), then make a cell array of function handles, there `fun1` is the name of one of your actual functions.

```
handles = {@fun1, @fun2, @fun3}
```

Then you can just use the index returned from your `max` term to get the correct function from the array. You can pass any arguments to the function using the following syntax.

```
handles{index}(args)
```

Using the style above makes the solution scalable, so you don't need a stack of `if` statements that require maintenance when the number of operations expands. If the functions are really simple you can always use lambdas (or anonymous functions in Matlab speak).

However, if you have a limited number of simple operations that are not likely to expand, you may choose to use a switch statement in your while loop instead. It conveys your intention better than a stack of `if` statements.

```
while 1
  [~, index]=max(flag);
  switch index
      case 1
          operation1
          flag = [x y z]
      case 2
          operation2
          flag = [x y z]
      otherwise
          operation3
          flag = [x y z]
    end
end
```

Comment: Nope they're not functions. The operations are all combined in one matlab file, and an IF statement currently triggers each operation in the order they are typed. So I wanted to change that so they're triggered depending on the value of the `flag` instead.

Comment: Just make your operations functions? Using the style above makes the solution scalable, so you don't need a stack of `if` that require maintenance when the number of operations expands.

Comment: Hmmm so the switcher will be a few lines of matlab code that basically uses a cell array of function handles ? While each operation has it's own matlab file basically right ?

Comment: That is one way of doing it, yes. Either that or you could use a `switch` statement that might be a bit neater than stacks of `if` statements

Comment: Do I still have to use the function handles with a switch statement ? I thought of using a switch statement but I didn't know how each operation will continuously loop and triggered by the `flag` value.

Comment: No function handles required for the switch version, you can just switch the index and use the index values as cases, placing the operation in the conditional block, followed by an updated flags value set. Your while loop is infinite, so on the next iteration, the flags index will be switched again.

Comment: I will try the switch statement before doing the functions (less work). I would really appreciate if you add that to the answer as well rather than just a comment.